# Python: minimize least squares error of function and need to pass constant

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

I'm trying to minimize the least squares error of a function, which I've done before. But this time I need to pass the function an extra constant each time it's called, in addition to the variable. Right now I'm doing something like:

```
def fun(x,y,c):
    return x[0]+x[1]*y+c
def error_fun(x,y,z,c):
    return fun(x,y,c)-z
def fit_data(c,data,ind_var):
    return least_squares(error_fun,x0,args=(ind_var,data,c))
```

But I don't think I'm doing this right.

Comment: If your error function (to minimize) is `error_fun`, then you should put `error_fun` as the first argument to `least_squares`, not `fun`. And then pass `c` as an additional variable in the `args` tuple.

Comment: Have a lookat [`curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit) as well. For a lot of minimization problems of this kind, the syntax of `curve_fit` can be clearer.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Typos. I will edit

Comment: With your edit, why do you think you're not doing it right? Do you get an error?

Comment: It seemed weird that my args contained my xdata, ydata and some constant. Also there is a bug in my code and I feel like its in how I'm doing this least squares bit

Comment: *"Also there is a bug in my code and I feel like its in how I'm doing this least squares bit"*: that statement doesn't really help: you know that there's a bug in your code, but *why*? How does it show?

Comment: *"It seemed weird that my args contained my xdata, ydata and some constant."* No, that's fine. Though you're naming your arguments incorrectly, causing confusion: do you mean `ind_var` & `data`, or do you mean `x` and `y`? Because there are `xdata` or `ydata` variables or parameters.  If I know what you mean, I can perhaps explain a bit better why it's fine this way.

Comment: I'm fitting a function where I have a pretty good idea of what the parameters should be. One comes out correct, the other is negative (but shouldn't be) I tried plotting the squared error over a grid of points using mathematica and the minimum is where I expect it to be. The landscape doesn't look very complicated either.

Comment: @Evert sorry. I meant ind_var and data instead of xdata and ydata.

Comment: Without example data, this is hard to judge. "Shouldn't be" isn't really a strong reason to not believe the fit. Why shouldn't it be? Or do you mean *can't be*, which is quite different. Show the *actual* example (code & data), and reasoning why you expect the incorrect parameter to be positive.

Comment: As for the tuple values used in the `args` parameter: `least_squares` *can* be used to minimize the function by just the parameters `x`. *Anything* else are extra parameters, even if they are, say, measured x and y values. Here, you really care about the fitted parameters only, the other parameters are just extra. And the third parameter, which just happens to be a constant, could at another time also be an array of values. This is why I mentioned `curve_fit`, which has a more intuitive interface if you are trying to minimize a set of y vs x measurements as function of parameters.

Comment: I understand. I found the minimum by hand essentially, which is why I am certain they should both be positive. I feel more confident about this part of my code now, thank you. I will try to fumble around a little more on my own (my data set is quite large). If I cannot figure it out, I will come back to posting. Thank you so much for your help!